# storing users information in a session

Tags: php

```
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $upass = $_POST['password'];

    //select users information from database
    $buildsql = "SELECT * FROM umembersd WHERE uusername = '$uname' AND       upassword = '$upass'";
    $myexec = mysqli_query($conn, $buildsql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    if($myexec->num_rows > 0){
        while($data = $myexec->fetch_assoc()){

            $_SESSION['no'] = 'id';
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = 'ufname';
            $_SESSION['lastname']= 'ulname';
            $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = 'uphone';
            $_SESSION['emailaddress']= 'uemail';
            $_SESSION['datejoined'] = 'uregdate';
            $_SESSION['datereg'] = 'uusername';

            header('location: index.php?successful');
        }
    }else{
        header('location: login.php?nerror');
    }
    }
```

Comment: first, i have not understand how to store data in a session, but i know how to start a session and how to destroy a session, but the problem now becomes how i can store users information in a session, so that i can use it in all my pages.  

After the user have successfully login, i want to store all user's informations in a session to enable me use it in all my pages, i really want to learn php step by step

i tried this after a successful login

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php for an introduction and usage details. Also [edit] your comment *into* the question. Explain what troubles you really have (seeing that you only assigned static values to the session array).

Comment: `$_SESSION['no'] = $data['id'];` etc would be a good start